# VueJS emitted event not getting picked up by parent component

Tags: vue.js

I am struggling to understand why an emitted event on a child component is not getting picked up by the parent.

The event is getting emitted from the child component - I can see it in the toolbar along with the correct values. The method that is tied to the event is not getting called on the parent component. `ChildComponent.vue` is a form that is imported into `ParentComponent.vue`.

Here is what I have (that's working but not).

**ParentComponent.vue**

```
<child-component/>

<div v-show="this.label === 'acme'" @label:name="handleLabelName">
    <h3>Hello World</h3>
    ...
</div>

...

methods: {
    handleLabelName(name) {
        console.log('handleManualType called');  // never getting here
        console.log('name: ', name);             // never getting here
    }
},
```

**ChildComponent.vue**

```
...

<button data-label="acme" @click="handleClick($event)">Click Me</button>

...

methods: {
    handleClick(event) {
    const label = event.target.dataset.label;
    this.$emit('label:name', label); // acme
},
```

The event *is* getting broadcast, but `handleLabelName` is never getting called. I've read through [this great article](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/how-to-emit-data-in-vue-beyond-the-vuejs-documentation) many times and I believe I'm following it correctly. Is there something I am doing wrong to make `handleLabelName` never get called? I've also tried wrapping everything in a div like so:

```
<div @label:name="handleLabelName">
    <div v-show="this.label === 'acme'">
        <h3>Hello World</h3>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

And still the same result. `handleLabelName` never gets called. I've also tried changing the event name/method to simple things like, `foo` and still no difference.

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: what happens if you remove : from the event name?

Comment: Same thing. It gets emitted correctly, but the method doesn't fire. I've tried changing the emitted name to `hello` (something simple) and haven't had any luck.

Comment: You’re binding event listening to a div element which is not the child component. So of course the event isn’t captured.

Comment: Hi @Terry - thank you for the feedback. When you say the `div` is not the child, I apologize, but I don't understand. In my child I'm emitting an event - that I'm trying to pick up in the parent. I updated the markup in my example to show how I'm calling the child.

Comment: Try @this="abc" and not :this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are listening for events on a `div` instead of listening to your child component. You must put your listener on the DOM element that sends the event. Try something like this :

```
<child-component @my-event-name="handleLabelName"/>
```

Another point is that you might prefer using kebab case to name your custom events. It might be a problem to name your event with this character ":" (see https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html)

Comment: Ah - I understand exactly what @Terry is saying now. I *was* emitting the event, but was not getting the event "out" of the component. I was (incorrectly) assuming that the event was just automatically getting sent out of the component and the parent just needed to have the listener. The binding needs to be on the child to get *out* of the child...so the parent can pick it up. Thank you both for your time and explanation!

Comment: You are right :)
And yes that was what @Terry said before, many thanks to him.